# Moq for Interface that Inherits from ICollection returns null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to run unit tests using Moq. I am fairly new to Moq and I have ran into a problem with this current unit test.
I have a controller that is fetching some items. The result is encapsulated within a generic interface using `ICollection`.

```
public interface IResult
{
}

public interface IListResult : ICollection<IResult>
{
}
```

My controller is simply calling a method that returns the result.

```
[HttpGet("get/{userId}/{pageSize}/{fetchNext}")]
public IActionResult GetConversations(int userId, int pageSize, bool fetchNext)
{
    try
    {
        GetConversationsByUserIdQuery query = new GetConversationsByUserIdQuery()
        {
            UserId = userId,
            PageSize = pageSize,
            FetchNext = fetchNext
        };
        var result = _mediator.GetConversationsByUserId(query);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

When I am running my unit test, the result always comes back null and I am failing to understand what I am missing in my set up.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1, 2 , false)]
[InlineData(1, 2 , true)]
public async void When_AddMessageToNewConversation_ThenSuccessfullyAdd(int userId, int pageSize, bool fetchNext)
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IMessageMediator> _mediator = new Mock<IMessageMediator>();
    Mock<IListResult> _listResult = new Mock<IListResult>();
    
    GetConversationsByUserIdQuery query = new GetConversationsByUserIdQuery()
    {
        UserId = userId,
        PageSize = pageSize,
        FetchNext = fetchNext
    };


    List<Conversation> expected = new List<Conversation>()
    {
        new Conversation()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Created_At = DateTimeOffset.Now
        }
    };

    _listResult.Setup(x => 
        x.GetEnumerator())
        .Returns(expected.GetEnumerator());

    GetConversationsByUserIdController controller = new GetConversationsByUserIdController(_mediator.Object);
    _mediator.Setup(x => 
        x.GetConversationsByUserId(query)).Returns(_listResult.Object);

    // Act
    IActionResult result = controller.GetConversations(userId, pageSize, fetchNext);

    // Assert
    Assert.True(result is OkResult);
}
```

The IMessageMediator is simply a delegator that handles implementation of queriers and commands. The IListResult is returned from a querier handler.

```
public class GetConversationsByUserIdQueryHandler: 
IQueryHandler<GetConversationsByUserIdQuery>
{
   private IRepository<Conversations_By_UserId> 
  _conversationByUserIdRepository;
  private IListResult _result;

public GetConversationsByUserIdQueryHandler(IRepository<Conversations_By_UserId> conversationByUserIdRepository,
    IListResult result)
{
    _conversationByUserIdRepository = conversationByUserIdRepository;
    _result = result;
}

public IListResult Handle(GetConversationsByUserIdQuery query)
{
    IEnumerable<Conversations_By_UserId> conversations = _conversationByUserIdRepository
        .Get(query.PageSize,
            query.FetchNext,
            message => message.UserId == query.UserId).ToList();
    
    if (conversations.Any())
    {
        foreach (Conversations_By_UserId m in conversations)
        {
            _result.Add(new Conversation()
            {
                Created_At = m.Created_At,
                Id = m.Id,
            });
        }
    }
    return _result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to mock both `IMessageMediator` and `IListResult`.

You should mock dependencies - it is `IMessageMediator` in your case - and your can setup it to return any result.

The other thing - you mock `_mediator` using query created in test, but in controller you create different query (references are different) and it is the reason of `null` result.

Change your test:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1, 2 , false)]
[InlineData(1, 2 , true)]
public async void When_AddMessageToNewConversation_ThenSuccessfullyAdd(int userId, int pageSize, bool fetchNext)
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IMessageMediator> _mediator = new Mock<IMessageMediator>();     

    List<Conversation> expected = new List<Conversation>()
    {
        new Conversation()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Created_At = DateTimeOffset.Now
        }
    };    
      
    GetConversationsByUserIdController controller = new GetConversationsByUserIdController(_mediator.Object);

             // It.IsAny<GetConversationsByUserIdQuery>()) instead of query
   _mediator.Setup(x => x.GetConversationsByUserId(It.IsAny<GetConversationsByUserIdQuery>()))

            // create fake result to return from mediator (no need to mock IListResult     
            .Returns(new ListResult() ...); // just create instance of IListResult with needed values

    // Act
    IActionResult result = controller.GetConversations(userId, pageSize, fetchNext);

    // Assert
    Assert.True(result is OkResult);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am wondering how the mocking of fake results would work since IListResult is an Interface?

Comment: @AndyJohnson, don't know if I understand your question in comment, but I'll try to answer. `_mediator` returns the result of type `IListResult`, there is some logic inside to return this result. Using mock you replace the real implementation with your own, but this implementation should return the result of the same type as real one. So here your can just set the desired result from `_mediator` (of type `IListResult`).

Comment: Sorry for the vague explanation. My question specifically comes with creating an instance of IListResult as per your comment. Since this is an interface, I will be unable to create an instance. Hence why I thought I need to mock it in order to specify that IListResult is returning a List of Conversations . I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: @AndyJohnson, i see your point, but why do you need an interface which is not implemented by any type?

Comment: @AndyJohnson, how `_mediator` creates the instance of `IListResult`?

Comment: Well, the point of using the interface is to provide a generic way of encapsulating results since there are multiple controllers fetching different kinds of data types.

Comment: @AndyJohnson, you're right, but `_mediator.GetConversationsByUserId()` (real implementation) somehow returns instances of `IListResult`?

Comment: I have updated my question with the returned instance of IListResult.

Comment: @AndyJohnson, `IListResult` is resolved using dependency injection for constructor of `GetConversationsByUserIdQueryHandler`?

Comment: Yes, and then used in the method to add the result after fetching the data.

Comment: @AndyJohnson, then there is a type that implements `IListResult` because DI creates instance of this type. You can create instance of the same type in your test.